# Javascript function reference best practices

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

```
function name( elements ){

    init( elements );

    var ret = {
        add : function( more ){
            $.extend(elements, more);
            init( more );
        }
    }

    function init( el ){
        $.each(el,function(name, selector){
            //some stuff....
        });
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I use this structure (that I've created by myself) very much...it's very simple and good to do thinks like this without use objects:

```
var reference = name({ one : $('#one'), two : $('#two') });

//and in a second moment...
reverence.add({ three : $('#tree') });
```

Is this a good practice or it isn't? is it better to use objects and istances? why?

Comment: What would be wrong with this object fabric? Btw, there seems to be no way to access `elements` again.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, constructors and prototypes (JavaScript's equivalent to traditional classes) lead to more readable and maintainable code. I had to read your example three times to figure out what it's doing (basically, creating a dictionary structure with an 'add' method).

Prototypes are more javascript-y, and use a paradigm that is common and well-known — and much simpler for someone else, or for you two years from now, to look back at and understand.

Consider how much easier the following is to read:

```
/** @constructor */
function Name(elememts) {
    this.elements = this._init(elements)
}

Name.prototype.add = function(more) {
    $.extend(this.elements, this._init(more));
}

Name.prototype._init = function(elements) {
    // some stuff...
}
```

Your method does get the advantage of hiding private functions. With traditional prototypical inheritance there is no 'private' keyword, so it's up to you to remember not to call a private method from outside the object itself. (Google's Closure Compiler does have a @private annotation and it will help you enforce it, but it's not exactly a perfect system.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use closures ... they are powerful thing in javascript... :)

```
var status = function (status) {
return {
get_status: function ( ) {
return status;
}
};
};

// Make an instance of status.
    var myStatus = status("amazed");
    document.writeln(myStatus.get_status( ));
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP is doing?